# Unable to update Pandas row in For loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using bnp-paribas-cardif-claims-management from Kaggle.
Dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/c/bnp-paribas-cardif-claims-management/data

```
df=pd.read_csv('F:\\Data\\Paribas_Claim\\train.csv',nrows=5000)
```

df.info() gives

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5000 entries, 0 to 4999
Columns: 133 entries, ID to v131
dtypes: float64(108), int64(6), object(19)
memory usage: 5.1+ MB
```

My requirement is :
I am trying to fill null values for columns with datatypes as int and object. I am trying to fill the nulls based on the target column.

My code is

```
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object','int64']).columns.to_list()
for cols in df_obj:
    df[( df['target'] == 1 )&( df[cols].isnull() )][cols]  = df[df['target'] == 1][cols].mode()
    df[( df['target'] == 0 )&( df[cols].isnull() )][cols]  = df[df['target'] == 0][cols].mode()
```

I am able to get output in below print statement:

```
df[( df['target'] == 1 )&( df[cols].isnull() )][cols]
```

also the able to print the values for `df[df['target'] == 0][cols].mode()` if I substitute `cols`.

But unable to replace the null values with mode values.
I tried `df.loc`, `df.at` options instead of `df[]` and `df[...] == np.nan` instead of `df[...].isnull()` but of no use.

Please assist if I need to do any changes in the code. Thanks.

Comment: please do not share a screenshot of your problem. share raw data and expected output

Comment: Please add the traceback error, if any, or describe what result you get instead of your expected result

Comment: So you need replace misisng values in object only? Because if integers columns then no missing values. Or do you think floats (numeric) columns?

Comment: For both object and int.

Comment: yes, because `NaN` is float, then integer column have no NaN, so cannot be replace, because not exist.

Comment: how about np.nan and isnull(). Unable to replace those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem is select integers columns, then no contain missing values (because `NaN` is `float`), so cannot be replaced. Possible solution is select all numeric columns and in loop set first value of mode per conditions with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for avoid chain indexing and [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) for return only first value (mode should return sometimes 2 values):

```
df=pd.read_csv('train.csv',nrows=5000)

#only numeric columns
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns.to_list()
#all columns
#df_obj = df.columns.to_list()

#print (df_obj)

for cols in df_obj:
    m1 = df['target'] == 1
    m2 = df['target'] == 0
    df.loc[m1 & (df[cols].isnull()), cols]  = df.loc[m1, cols].mode().iat[0]
    df.loc[m2 & (df[cols].isnull()), cols]  = df.loc[m2, cols].mode().iat[0]
```

Another solution with replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
for cols in df_obj:
    m1 = df['target'] == 1
    m2 = df['target'] == 0
    df.loc[m1, cols]  = df.loc[m1, cols].fillna(df.loc[m1, cols].mode().iat[0])
    df.loc[m2, cols]  = df.loc[m2, cols].fillna(df.loc[m2, cols].mode().iat[0])
```

---

```
print (df.head())
   ID  target            v1        v2 v3        v4         v5            v6  \
0   3       1  1.335739e+00  8.727474  C  3.921026   7.915266  2.599278e+00   
1   4       1 -9.543625e-07  1.245405  C  0.586622   9.191265  2.126825e-07   
2   5       1  9.438769e-01  5.310079  C  4.410969   5.326159  3.979592e+00   
3   6       1  7.974146e-01  8.304757  C  4.225930  11.627438  2.097700e+00   
4   8       1 -9.543625e-07  1.245405  C  0.586622   2.151983  2.126825e-07   

             v7            v8  ...      v122      v123          v124  v125  \
0  3.176895e+00  1.294147e-02  ...  8.000000  1.989780  3.575369e-02    AU   
1 -9.468765e-07  2.301630e+00  ...  1.499437  0.149135  5.988956e-01    AF   
2  3.928571e+00  1.964513e-02  ...  9.333333  2.477596  1.345191e-02    AE   
3  1.987549e+00  1.719467e-01  ...  7.018256  1.812795  2.267384e-03    CJ   
4 -9.468765e-07 -7.783778e-07  ...  1.499437  0.149135 -9.962319e-07     Z   

           v126          v127      v128  v129      v130          v131  
0  1.804126e+00  3.113719e+00  2.024285     0  0.636365  2.857144e+00  
1  5.521558e-07  3.066310e-07  1.957825     0  0.173913 -9.932825e-07  
2  1.773709e+00  3.922193e+00  1.120468     2  0.883118  1.176472e+00  
3  1.415230e+00  2.954381e+00  1.990847     1  1.677108  1.034483e+00  
4  5.521558e-07  3.066310e-07  0.100455     0  0.173913 -9.932825e-07  

[5 rows x 133 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a sample data so I'll just give the methods I think you can use to solve your problem.

Try to read your DataFrame with `na_filter = False` that way your columns with `np.nan` or has `null` values will be replaced by blanks instead.

Then, during your loop use the `''` as your identifier for null values. Easier to tag than trying to use the type of the value you are parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`pd.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) should help.

```
# random dataset
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                    [3, 2, np.nan, 1],
                    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                    [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
                    columns=list('ABCD'))

print(df)

    A   B   C   D
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0
1   3.0 2.0 NaN 1
2   NaN NaN NaN 5
3   NaN 3.0 NaN 4
```

---

Assuming you want to replace missing values with the mode value of a given column, I'd just use:

```
df.fillna({'A':df.A.mode()[0],'B':df.B.mode()[0]})

    A   B   C   D
0   3.0 2.0 NaN 0
1   3.0 2.0 NaN 1
2   3.0 2.0 NaN 5
3   3.0 3.0 NaN 4
```

---

This would also work if you needed a mode value from a subset of values from given column to fill NaNs with.

```
# let's add 'type' column

    A   B   C   D   type
0   NaN 2.0     0   1
1   3.0 2.0     1   1
2   NaN NaN     5   2
3   NaN 3.0     4   2
```

For example, if you want to fill `df['B']` NaNs with the mode value of each row that is equal to `df['type']` 2:

```
df.fillna({
    'B': df.loc[df.type.eq(2)].B.mode()[0] # type 2 
})

    A   B   C   D   type
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0   1
1   3.0 2.0 NaN 1   1
2   NaN 3.0 NaN 5   2
3   NaN 3.0 NaN 4   2
       # ↑ this would have been '2.0' hadn't we filtered the column with df.loc[]
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am trying to fill mode based on a condition ( depending on other column's value).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this

```
df[( df['target'] == 1 )&( df[cols].isnull() )][cols] = ...
```

Do NOT chain index, especially when assigning. See *Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?* section in this [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Instead use `loc`:

```
df.loc[(df['target'] == 1) & (df[cols].isnull()), 
       cols] = df.loc[df['target'] == 1,
                      cols].mode()
```

Comment: Facing error :SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Thank you, updated. The idea is use `df.loc[A,B]` instead of `df[A][B]` or `df.loc[A][B]`.

Comment: Not working.
df.v3.unique() gives array(['C', nan, 'A', 'B'], dtype=object)